# Rscript pointing to incorrect R version in local build

Tags: r, rscript

I recently installed a local version of R 3.1.0 on a Linux Redhat server as follows:

```
# from R-3.1.0 directory 
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)
make
make install
```

In addition, I've updated PATH and R_LIBS in my .bashrc. If I run `path/to/local/R/bin/Rscript --version`, then it returns the proper version number. However, if I give it a test script that prints `sessionInfo` it yields information from the system-wide R installation.

Is there any more I need to do to run the local version of R using Rscript? From reading a similar issue [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/regenerate-Rscript-after-moving-R-installation-tp4676642p4676648.html), it looks like the code above should be all that's necessary. There's a similar SO issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935708/rscript-issue-using-different-version-of-r), but it's unresolved.

**Edit:**
I just fired up Ubuntu in a VM and was able to install R locally and run Rscript without problem (using the same commands listed above). Have I gone crazy? Is there anything that might be floating around the Redhat environment on this server that might mess up the installation? Sanity checks?

Comment: when you do `which Rscript` does the new one come up? When you updated your PATH, did you make sure your local version is found before the system wide one?

Comment: `which Rscript` returns the local (3.0.1) version. The local precedes everything else in PATH. If I had a script named `test_script.R`, I could run `path/to/local/R/bin/R` and source it without problem, but `path/to/local/R/bin/Rscript` would run the system-wide R. I'm guessing paths are specified during compile-time that are causing trouble..?